# am getting confused between reading a csv file in R notebooks(kaggle) and Rstudio

Tags: r, csv, kaggle

```
calorie_hour <- read.csv("C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/Fitbit/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16/hourlyCalories_merged.csv")
```

above is the code I used in Rstudio and it worked. In Kaggle notebook it failed.

```
calorie_hour <- read.csv("C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/Fitbit/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16/hourlyCalories_merged.csv")
```

above is the code I used in R notebook in Kaggle.

where am I going wrong? and what should I do in future to avoid this

Comment: It might be helpful to see the exact error. Kaggle has specific pages dedicated to solving missing file problems. If R can find a file in one platform but not another, it is generally a result of where the file is stored and the working directory.

Comment: Also, in Kaggle the directory path you use may be different, its running in the cloud not your computer.

Comment: It’s an absolute path. It should succeed if the file is there. Is it?

Comment: the file was in my computer but then i uploaded it to kaggle site